# Strange characters after updating project via Visual Studio SVN

Tags: svn, visualsvn

We encounter strange characters whenever we update project using Visual Studio SVN as shown on the image below. This problem occurs commonly *.csproj files and *.cs files in the project. Is there any solution to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: it shows conflicts, your version and server version

Comment: @programtreasures Thanks for reply. As we are new for SVN, could you please give some suggestion to fix the problem?

Comment: you can do manually edit the file, or using vs you can resolve conflict from comparing tool

Comment: @programtreasures It does not seem to be practical to delete all of these lines for several files after each synhronization, does it? :((

Comment: you need to use merge tool like win merge http://winmerge.org/?lang=en

Comment: With whick file do I compare the *.csproj after synch? With *.csproj.mine file?

Comment: right click on file and select resolve conflict under svn options